# How to (auto)-configure repository/project scaffold Azure DevOps/GitHub?

Tags: python, github, azure-devops, scaffolding

This is what I want to do, as soon as someone in your org create a repository in Azure DevOps (or GitHub), a defined project scaffold/structure is build for them. For example, a fresh repo (`my_proj`) is created, then DevOps/GitHub creates such a folder structure for you (you defined it somewhere):

```
───my_proj
   │   ReadMe.md
   │
   ├───docs
   ├───res
   │   ├───file
   │   └───img
   ├───scr
   └───tests
```

I know you can do these things after you clone the repo using some codes/libraries, but is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in "[Create template git-repo in in azure devops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61452886/6309)", there is no native feature allowing you to chose a given Git repository template when initializing a new Project with Azure DevOps.

That means you could:

- clone a template repository (created in advance on Azure DevOps=
- push it back to your new empty Azure DevOp repository (by changing its URL with `git remote set-url ...`)

You can see that approach atomated through Azure piplines with "[Create a new repository from a template in Azure DevOps](https://stephenallwright.com/project-template-repository-azure-devops/)" from [Stephen Allwright](https://stephenallwright.com/about/)

> 1. Create a repository in Azure DevOps that you would like to use as your template. Let's call it 'project-template'
> 2. Create a second repository to contain the build pipeline you will create. We will call this 'utilities'. This is a useful repository to have in general to house all your automation pipelines and other functions which improve the ease of development
> 3. Create a starter build pipeline and host it within the utilities repository
> 4. Create a variable within the pipeline UI called 'project-name', this will be used as the name of your newly created repository. Defining this variable within the UI allows us to choose a project name when we run the pipeline in DevOps
> 5. Use the following code, making sure to replace 'devops-organisation', 'devops-project', 'email', and 'user' with your own values

Comment: Thanks! don't you think this should be a native feature? or I'm missing something here

Comment: @mas It absolutely could, as it is already for GitHub (owned by Microsoft, which hosts Azure): https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-template-repository. I don't see that feature in past releases, or in preview though: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?category=developer-tools,devops&query=template